# Cant connect my website to a database on a VPS

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp, remote-access

Well i got a free host to run my website, i uploaded all the files:
[image]
The point is: my website requires to read/write accounts from a database, located on my VPS (Windows Server). 
My website connects through:

[image]

Where abboud_auth and abboud_world are my databases, IP is my VPS' IP and user and password are my user and password of my navicat, which is also running on my VPS.

So, now on my VPS, i have my databases:

[image]

[image]

So, the problem is that when i run my website i cant connect to my databases.
I'm using Xampp, and its mysql config is:

[image]

In fact, i tested the remote access with this web, and i cant connect:

[image]

The obvious question: what should i do?

Thanks ^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Comment: hi i tried that solutions and are not working for me @WillParky93